# Arduino + motor driver (L293D) power consumption

Tags: power, motor, battery

Please help me on [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/35445/arduino-motor-driver-l293d-power-consumption) question.

Original question : 
My chip consists of 1 arduino nano and  3 [L293D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf) motor driver. This chip is for controlling motors and other equipments. My question is about how to calculate power consumption of my chip. I searched for about voltage settings of arduiono nano and L293D motor driver, but there are many phusical thinks that i cannot understand. How many hours 2000 mah battery enough for.

Note : 
Motors and other equipments will have own power supply. That i say it is just for [Arduino Nano](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano), Bluetoot adapter for arduino (HC-05) and 3 motor driver (L293D).

Comment: If you are powering all modules from the bench power supply, note down the voltage and the current. Product of the two will give you power consumption.

Comment: It also depends on the voltage provides by power bank.

Comment: I cannot got power settings of [L293D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf). I read technical specification but cannot understand

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question as you already have it connected and working, correct me if i am wrong. you are only looking for the battery life time estimation.

Comment: are you driving three motor with one L293D or you are using 3 L293D motor driver ICs?

Comment: Yes i connect via power adapter. And it works fine. But it should be with battery not adapter. And I want to calculate which kind of battery i should use. How many Mah  battery is enoght for 3(for examle .. maybe 5 hours )  hours.

Note : I use 3 L293D and can control 6 motors with it

Comment: how much current do you need to use to drive the motor? the current to the motor is supplied by the L293D device and hence, it matters. in short, share the motor specs.

Comment: About motor specs i cannot say exactly. Bu i can say this is formula 1 car something like [this](https://goo.gl/photos/CLsxMN8bVz21rWz89) with 4 AA battery

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple stacks.  StackExchange policy is against cross-posting.

Comment: Did you even read the question? This is 1% about arduino  and 99% about general electonics... this question does not belong to arduino stack, why do you moderators keep moving everything with "Arduino" written on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate L293D power usage, you need to lookup the datasheet and check the Voh and Vol. These are the High level voltage and Low level voltage.

On Texas Instruments datasheet, we have:
[image]

So you will lose about 1.4V when your output is -0.6A, and 1.2V when your output is 0.6A. If your motor uses 2 outputs (bi-directional) then you have to add the losses.

Then, to get the power dissipated on the power side of the L293D, you take this voltage drop and multiply by the motor´s current.

**Example:**
Lets say your motor is using 0.6Amps and your power source is 5V + 24V @ 25°C (just like in the datasheet).

The power loss in the L293D is aprox.: (1.4V + 1.2V) x 0.6A = 1,56W.
Since you´ve lost 2.6V in the L293D, your motor will use: (24V - 2.6V) x 0.6A = 12,84W.

To measure this directly on your real circuit, use a multimeter in Ampere mode to measure current, and Volt mode to measure the voltage on the motor terminals when it is on.

As for the arduino, your battery has 2000mAh and I assume it is a 7,4V battery. So it has 2000mAh x 7,4V = 14800mWh of energy stored in it.

If you are running your arduino at 5V, then: 14800mWh / 5V = 2960mAh at 5V.
Now let´s say your arduino and it´s modules, the L293D´s and the motors are using 500mA average, then your battery will last: 2960mAh / 500mA = 5.92 hours in theory.
Why "in theory"? because in real life it is impossible to extract all the energy from inside a battery. A minimum ammount of energy has to remain inside it and some power is lost when you extract it´s energy.

Of course, this is a very raw calculation. In reality, you have to calculate power used in every component. But by calculating the "big guns" first you can get an idea of where you stand.

Basic power loss calculation is done by multiplying voltage drop by the current in each circuit. Voltage drop is the difference between your volts before and after the component.